# Instagram API Login no longer available in 2020?

Tags: instagram, facebook-login, instagram-api

I am not a developer.

I host an easy iPhone application where users can choose between a registration through Facebook or Instagram. Almost 90% choose the Instagram way and I don't collect any special data. Only the Firstname and Lastname. Most of the things need to be filled out anyway (like the Instagram name because I do not get this from the token or the email address).

Now my developer team told me that Instagram will stop working and we need to remove this from the app. All users most login with Facebook from now on. I am using a Flutter App which works on Android and Apple.

My App is only for a specific kind of people and I felt better to use their Instagram token for a registration because it's like a "fake check" when people know, that their "real" Instagram is connected.

4 Questions:

- is it really true that Instagram shuts down this "login with Instagram" functionality?
- what happens to all the people who registered with the Instagram token? if they switch from Instagram to the Facebook login it would mean that there is no link to their profile any more and they do need to register almost from scratch.
- the company offered me to create a own registration/user Form but I was quite happy with the Instagram way because I do not need to save a username and a password for my app.
- I also received a mail from Apple that they want to use every iPhone app to use "login with apple" functionality. Will this also be mandatory in the future?

For me the situation is very bad because it will cost a lot of money to redo everything and I would appreciate to get some help or tips how I can handle the situation.

Comment: Could you ask your developer for a link to the Instagram documentation that reveals what change they are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Q: Why should I migrate to the Instagram Graph API platform?
>
> A: In January 2018, we publicly announced our plans to shut down the Instagram Legacy API platform through a sequenced approach. We plan to disable the final permission remaining on the Legacy API ("Basic Permission") on June 29, 2020 and any existing apps using the Legacy API will no longer have access. We encourage you to apply for permissions to Instagram Basic Display API and migrate Legacy API calls before June 29 to avoid interruption of service to your app and business. Note that App Review submissions can take up to a week or longer to process. Refer to the developer documentation to learn more.

[Source](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)

In short, it looks like you need to migrate to the Graph API. If your developer believes there is a reason why you cannot use Instagram at all, perhaps he/she could ask a specific question about that, indicating what specific problem is being encountered.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. I really appreciate it. What does that mean so switch to the GRAPH API? I read that its only for business accounts and not for private accounts on instagram?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea - I don't use Instagram. This is a question that your developer should be answering for you. I think they have given you a very partial answer ("won't work any more") and we would need to see why exactly they are saying that. Instagram still appear to be offering an API. A Graph API, in general, also runs over HTTP, but you need a library to send and receive requests. It is more flexible than REST, which is probably what you are using at the moment.

Comment: I think the questions about what features Instagram offer, and who they offer them to, are questions for Instagram (Customer or Technical Support) and not here. Since your developer has a technical background, it make sense for them to do the digging for you, and to present that information to you in a meaningful way, so you can make the appropriate business decisions.